# XML Deserialization with C# .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization

I Have this XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Object>
        <referenceName>People</referenceName>
        <query>select * from people</query>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <referenceName>Countries</referenceName>
        <query>select * from countries</query>
    </Object>
</Root>
```

I need to convert into an object with C#.

I got confused how to do it. 
Kindly note that I can have alot of objects in the xml file.

I know that i have to use an [XMLArray......

Thanks

Comment: actually, you **don't** have the use `[XmlArray]` here... see example in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest trick here is at the VS command line:

```
xsd example.xml
xsd example.xsd /classes
```

Et voila; one example.cs file with example C# that shows how to get that xml from .NET objects via `XmlSerializer`.

In this case, I **expect** the following would work:

```
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("Object")]
    public List<SomeOtherObject> Objects { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOtherObject
{
    [XmlElement("referenceName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("query")]
    public string Query { get; set; }
}
```

update: validated it; yup, it works...

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(
    new StringReader(xml)))
{
    var obj = (Root)ser.Deserialize(reader);
    // use obj
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [xsd.exe tool to generate an initial set of classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) to start with. Once you have those, tweak if needed (post the generated classes) and use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` to deserialize back into the runtime object.